# Load MySQL data when click a div

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a system where the user can select game characters he has (characters stored in another table). If he has 2 characters, he should see two div's with the data of characters in that div - etc.

I know how to make the divs, but how can I load that specific character data he clicked to the users SESSION? For example he pressed character number 2, how do I know he selected the 2nd character he has in the database?

The problem is that every user might have different amount of divs, how do I know which data should I load to the session and continue with the code. I hope you understand my request. Do I somehow assign a number to each div?

Comment: Could you post some relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your chars in the database should have a unique id, which identifies him (primary key with auto increment).
So get the click, you could add a `<a>` tag arround the div which do the redirect and handles the selection of your character

```
<a href="selectChar.php?char=<?php echo $char['id']; ?>">
    <div>..</div>
</a>
```

So if you click on the div, the selectChar.php script is called with the get param `char`. This param could be accessed with `$_GET`.

```
$char_id = $_GET['char'];
```

and with this id you would find the char in your database and save it to the session (or do whatever you want with it..)

Comment: I thought of this, but what if the user edits the URL, changes the ID to someone elses character? Then he can access other people characters like that.

Comment: Of course you should add some owner field to the character, which would be checked

Comment: `SELECT * FROM character WHERE id=? AND owner=?` where id is the char_id and owner is the user id(which should be stored in the session)